# Redirect page on date and time from Everwebinar URL

Tags: javascript, redirect

I would like to be able to redirect a custom Everwebinar confirmation page (on my domain) visitor to a specific URL at a given date and time that is contained in a confirmation page URL.

The confirmation page URL looks like this:

`https://website.com/pagename?preview_theme_id=2151207349?wj_lead_email=email%40outlook.com&wj_lead_first_name=FirstName&wj_lead_last_name=LastName&wj_lead_phone_country_code=&wj_lead_phone_number=&wj_lead_unique_link_live_room=https%3A%2F%2Fevent.webinarjam.com%2Fgo%2Flive%2F1%2Fk6znqu2twiyznhp42&wj_event_ts=1658918700&wj_event_tz=Europe%2FLondon&wj_next_event_date=Wednesday%2C+24+August+2022&wj_next_event_time=2%3A00+PM&wj_next_event_timezone=London+GMT+%2B1`

A simple javascript redirect would be suitable as long as the redirect date, time and URL are all pulled from the confirmation page URL above as each visitor will have a unique URL.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: There are several things that you should clarify for your question. Firstly, there are 2 different dates available in the *confirmation page URL* you provided (***wj_event_ts*** and ***wj_next_event_date***), which date are you needed to use? Also it looks like there is a url provided as a parameter(***wj_lead_unique_link_live_room***) and I'm not sure if that is the intended redirect location or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, it should be noted that the **confirmation page URL** you gave as an example contains two question marks, which is not valid. This may be a typo, but there should only be one question mark before the URL search parameters, with all search parameters being separated by an ampersand (**&**).

That being said, there area several methods available to get the values of the URL search parameters and then redirect based on the date/time provided in the URL. The main thing used here is `URLSearchParams()`, which allows you to get an object that contains all of the search parameters available. From there, the **wj_event_ts** is a timestamp that can be used to compare dates/times.

For this example I will use the URL you provided, but if this JavaScript is being run on that confirmation page, I have commented out how to grab the current URL instead.

```js
// If run on the actual confirmation page, use:
// let currentURL = window.location.href;

let currentURL = new URL("https://website.com/pagename?preview_theme_id=2151207349&wj_lead_email=email%40outlook.com&wj_lead_first_name=FirstName&wj_lead_last_name=LastName&wj_lead_phone_country_code=&wj_lead_phone_number=&wj_lead_unique_link_live_room=https%3A%2F%2Fevent.webinarjam.com%2Fgo%2Flive%2F1%2Fk6znqu2twiyznhp42&wj_event_ts=1658918700&wj_event_tz=Europe%2FLondon&wj_next_event_date=Wednesday%2C+24+August+2022&wj_next_event_time=2%3A00+PM&wj_next_event_timezone=London+GMT+%2B1"),
searchParams = new URLSearchParams(currentURL.search),
nextEventDate = new Date(`${searchParams.get("wj_next_event_date")} ${searchParams.get("wj_next_event_time")} ${searchParams.get("wj_next_event_timezone").substr(searchParams.get("wj_next_event_timezone").indexOf("GMT"))}`);

if(Date.now() >= searchParams.get("wj_event_ts")*1000) {
  // It is currently past the date in the URL
  console.log("Redirecting... Current Event");
  //window.location.href = searchParams.get("wj_lead_unique_link_live_room");
}

// If you want to use the next_event_date value instead, use this section
if(Date.now() >= nextEventDate.getTime()) {
  console.log("Redirecting... Next Event");
  //window.location.href = searchParams.get("wj_lead_unique_link_live_room");
}
```

**EDIT**
It looks like you have multiple dates in the URL and it was not specified which date/time you would like to use. I have added another commented out section to use the *next_event_date* value instead of the *event_date* timestamp.

Comment: Yes, that is indeed a typo, the ?preview_theme_id=2151207349 shouldn't be there.

So from my basic understanding of javascript, the above solution gets the timestamp from the URL redirects but to a static URL that needs to be specified. How would that be modified to use the 'wj_lead_unique_link_live_room' parameter from the URL? Many thanks

Comment: We must have cross-posted, the timestamp would be fine, I had edited the other date manually.

Comment: @simonv4549 Both `if` statements that check for dates have a commented out line that redirects to the *wj_lead_unique_link_live_room* value. Just remove the `//` in front of either line to redirect. If you only need to use *wj_event_ts* (current event timestamp), use the first `if` statement. If you wanted to use *wj_next_event_date*, use the second `if` statement.

Comment: Would I be correct in thinking this would be my final script as I only want to use the one parameter of wj_event_ts?

`// If run on the actual confirmation page, use:
let currentURL = window.location.href;
searchParams = new URLSearchParams(currentURL.search);

if(Date.now() >= searchParams.get("wj_event_ts")*1000) {
  // It is currently past the date in the URL
  console.log("Redirecting... Current Event");
  window.location.href = searchParams.get("wj_lead_unique_link_live_room");
}`

Comment: @simonv4549 Basically yes. However, after the `currentURL` declaration, replace the semicolon with a comma (`;` to `,`).

Comment: I'm testing this with a local HTML file and an updated timestamp and I get instantly redirected to /null even though the timestamp is set to the future.

Comment: @simonv4549 I would need to see the URL being used. Redirecting to null implies that the `wj_lead_unique_link_live_room` URL parameter is null or was not able to be read. This could be because of an issue in the URL itself or something else. The instant redirection would also be for the same reason because if it can't read the timestamp, it will effectively always trigger the redirect.

Comment: I ended up modifying your code and got it working, I posted my solution below as an answer. Thanks for your input, really helped me get the solution I needed.

Answer (score 0):

I used another method of getting the URL parameters and that worked.

```
const queryString = window.location.search;
console.log(queryString);
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);

if (urlParams.has('wj_event_ts')) {
  if(Date.now() >= urlParams.get('wj_event_ts')*1000) {
    // It is currently past the date in the URL
    console.log('Redirecting... Current Event');
    window.location.href = urlParams.get('wj_lead_unique_link_live_room');
  }
}
```